Cesium Terrain Builder Docker not outputting correct layer.json
I've been using the Cesium Terrain Builder Docker to try and create cesium tiles from a tiff image. This is the command I've been using ctb-tile -f Terrain -C -N -l -o test-tiles test.tif
The tiff has been reprojected to EPSG:4326 prior to processing as recommended.
I've followed the git readme step-by-step, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.
My tif should be located in the UK and the bounds are incorrect in the json so nothing is appearing for me in Cesium
{
  "tilejson": "2.1.0",
  "name": "test",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "format": "heightmap-1.0",
  "attribution": "",
  "schema": "tms",
  "tiles": [ "{z}/{x}/{y}.terrain?v={version}" ],
  "projection": "EPSG:4326",
  "bounds": [ -180.00, -90.00, 0.00, 90.00 ],
  "available": [
    [ { "startX": 0, "startY": 0, "endX": 0, "endY": 0 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 1, "startY": 1, "endX": 1, "endY": 1 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 3, "startY": 3, "endX": 3, "endY": 3 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 7, "startY": 6, "endX": 7, "endY": 6 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 15, "startY": 12, "endX": 15, "endY": 12 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 31, "startY": 25, "endX": 31, "endY": 25 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 62, "startY": 51, "endX": 62, "endY": 51 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 125, "startY": 103, "endX": 125, "endY": 103 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 250, "startY": 207, "endX": 250, "endY": 207 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 501, "startY": 415, "endX": 501, "endY": 415 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 1002, "startY": 831, "endX": 1002, "endY": 831 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 2004, "startY": 1662, "endX": 2004, "endY": 1662 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 4008, "startY": 3324, "endX": 4009, "endY": 3324 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 8017, "startY": 6649, "endX": 8018, "endY": 6649 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 16035, "startY": 13298, "endX": 16037, "endY": 13299 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 32071, "startY": 26596, "endX": 32074, "endY": 26598 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 64143, "startY": 53193, "endX": 64149, "endY": 53197 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 128286, "startY": 106387, "endX": 128298, "endY": 106394 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 256573, "startY": 212774, "endX": 256597, "endY": 212788 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 513147, "startY": 425549, "endX": 513194, "endY": 425576 } ]
   ,[ { "startX": 1026295, "startY": 851099, "endX": 1026388, "endY": 851153 } ]
  ]
}

